# Private S3 static website accessed only by API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I want to set up a static S3 website that is only accessible via API Gateway, so what I've done is.

**S3 side**
1. Enabled static website hosting on the S3 bucket.
2. Blocked all public access.
3. Put in a bucket policy that only allows my VPC Endpoint to access it.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "VPCe",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VPCe",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket.com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-my-vpce"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

**API Gateway side**
1. Mapped that same VPCE to the API
2. Created a proxy resource
3. In the integration request, I made it HTTP and put my S3 website URL as the endpoint URL, content handling as passththrough.
4. But when I test this through APIGW, I get access denied.

**Is there something I'm missing, or am I wrong to expect this to work?**

---

I get a 403, Access Denied on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Mapped that same VPCE to the API"?

Comment: Private API, I put it in the settings under endpoint configuration -> Private and with that VPCE Id

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood the VPCE in this context. The value of the condition key `aws:SourceVpce` in the bucket policy is the ID of the S3 VPC endpoint resource. However, the ones configured under endpoint configuration in API gateway are `execute-api` interface VPC endpoint for API Gateway. These two IDs refer to different things.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set up a static S3 website that is only accessible via API Gateway,

You **can't do this**, as its not possible. S3 static websites are only accessible through **public URL**, thus you need to access it from the internet.

They are not meant to be accessed from VPC using private IP addresses or any VPC endpoints.

If you want to have private static website, you have to **host it yourself** on private EC2 instance or ECS container.